# How to create compile-time config class from build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

We have 'buildConfigField' method available in buildTypes which will create a static final variable in BuildConfig class. Also when we add any resource to the xml file, android by default creates an ID constant in R.java file. I want to understand the implementation behind this.

I want to create a method in android project inside the build.gradle file, which will read the json file and create class and its related static final member variables.

```
{
  "Config": [
    {
      "name": "usernameType",
      "type": "String",
      "value": "text"
    }
  ]
}
```

which will be created like this:

```
public static final Class Config {

  public static final Item username = new Item("<item_type>","<item_name>","<item_value>");

  public class Item {
    public String name, type, value;
    public Item(String name, String type, String value){
      this.name=name;
      this.type=type;
      this.value;
    }

}
```

I don't have any idea how can I implement this idea, which will basically create the configuration file at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Gradle plugin that defines a Gradle task that can read in the JSON, then use [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) to write out your Java file.

You wind up with a:

- Gradle `Plugin` object that knows how to attach itself to the Android build process at the right spot and creates a...
- Gradle `DefaultTask` object that can configure and run...
- some plain (non-Android) Java code that reads in the JSON (e.g., via Gson) and uses JavaPoet

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/PluginStub) demonstrates the basics of setting up a Gradle plugin, with a full explanation in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/writing-a-gradle-plugin) from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android). [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Staticizer) does pretty much what you want, though my JSON and Java are somewhat different than yours. It is covered in detail in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/code-generation) from my book.

In principle, you could do this all in Gradle, though the amount of code needed to pull this off exceeds what I typically see in `build.gradle` scripts.